# Jquery Timer doesnt work in IE9

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer, timer, signalr

we are displaying timer in the frontend of an auction portal.

we are using SignalR framework to broadcast auction time from the database.

We are able to get it to work absolutely great on Firefox, safari, opera and chrome.

BUT it doest work IE9.

***CheckList we have done at our end.***

1. all the javascript includes are done

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
   <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css"
       rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <script src="../../Scripts/modernizr-1.7.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   ```
2. we have done the connection.hub.start call

   ```
   var chat = $.connection.chat;
   $.connection.hub.start(function () {
       chat.send("Finished loading1");
   });
   ```
3. This is how i make an ajax call to the controller. so that i get relevant data in the front end view.

   ```
   function getTimer() {
       var tim;
       getAuc();
       var postData = { values: dataArray };
       try {
           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "../../Home/PushTimer",
               data: postData,
               success: function (data) {
                   if (data == "Null") {
                       return;
                   }
                   var i = 0;
                   for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                       assignTimer(data[i]);
                   };
               },
               dataType: "json",
               traditional: true
           });
       }
       catch (exception) { }
       return;
   };
   ```
4. If it works properly in firefox, chrome, safari and opera, what can be an issue with Internet Explorer.

Comment: `**$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../../Home/PushTimer",
            data: postData,**`

Comment: How exactly is it failing?  You should remove the try/catch and add a error or complete handler on the ajax call.  Check with fiddler - is the request hitting the server?  Does the request/response look the same in firefox vs ie, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I see an extra semicolan after your for loop. Might this be the reason? I know for a fact that IE is very strict about any extra semi colans that appear in your scripts.
Just cross verify once

Comment: the semi colon will just be an empty statement.  IE is more finicky over trailing commas in object definitions.

Comment: @drch I have had issues with extra semicolons in IE 7/8/9

Comment: Nope No success!   $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../../Home/PushTimer",
            data: postData,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data == "Null") {
                    return;
                }
                var i = 0;
                for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    assignTimer(data[i]);
                }
            },
            dataType: "json",
            traditional: true
        })

Comment: removed the semicolon. No Success.